# How would gravity affect a torus-shaped planet?

Tags: planets, gravity, life

My planet is a Super Earth about twice the mass of Earth. I'm not asking how it formed, although that would be nice to know. I mostly just want to know how long it would stay a torus shape, and how it would affect other other objects(including life on the surface, if habitable).

Comment: This question is not assuming magic can solve the problem.  So not really a duplicate.  But the answers are pretty much the same, so this question is a good sign post.

Comment: This is really a physics/math problem.  Basically just apply calculus to Newtonian gravity.  A simple Google search gives ~240K hits, like this one:

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  This question is very, very broad.  Asking how gravity can affect "other objects including life..." asks about every grain of sand, every amoeba, all the way up to trees, fish, and people.  The SE model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  This question must be narrowed considerably.  Thanks.

Comment: @JBH, community means the OP accepted that the suggested duplicate provides an answer. Which then makes me ask why the OP accepted also an answer here...

Comment: @L.Dutch, Oh!  I had no idea.  I'll delete my comment (although you do ask a good question....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't exist and it can't support life.

Such a thing would have to be constructed in space.  It would not produce any gravity unless it was spinning, and then only on the inside.  With just rock holding it together, it would quickly fly apart and break up into asteroids floating in space.  Then, over a few million years, they would crash back into each other and begin to form a proper planet.

For any of this to work, you would need magic, or it would have to be artificial.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you checkout this video on the topic made by the channel Artifexion [Artifexian - If planets were donuts](https://youtu.be/1J4iIBKJHLA). Send him son love and tell him I sent you ;)

To summarise the video:
The interior equator would be extremely rugged and mountainous. The planet would have to spin at incredible speeds to keep it’s donut-goodness which in turn will cause incredible storms spun up by the planets rotation. Their would be volcanic hotspots around the pols, so polar rings of fire (that’s metal;). A moon could orbit through the hole in the planet but would likely cause a collapse of the planet, so a plain boring equatorial orbit would be most likely. And gravity would vary on the planet just as a cutaway would be egg-shaped rather then round.

Comment: Since the video might go down in the future.  Can you add to your answer some details from the video?

Comment: In short, the planet would have to spin incredibly fast to generate enough centrifugal forces to counteract the pull of gravity. The gravity would be strongest at the equator’s and lowest slightly inwards from the poles. The continents would be extremely mountainous on the inside Polar rings of fire and the inside of the torus would never quite go dark. Cyclones would be much extreme intense and much more common and a moon could orbit through the hole in the middle but would most likely be on a flat orbit around the outer equator because the extreme instability of the planet. Watch the video.

Comment: You can add that to your answer.

Comment: I still like your answer, even though I know my question is answered better by this: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/58393.

Comment: @EnricoCogliati I gave it my best -_^

Comment: Welcome to the site Thunderwazp.  SE is a little different than standard discussion forums.  Answers should directly address the question and not rely on outside sources as things disappear from the web all the time.  You can edit your answer to summarize the key points and keep the link as a reference.  If you choose not to edit this answer will likely get converted to a comment on the question.

Comment: For more info on how the site works, check out the [help] and [tour].  Happy World Building.